# Why am I getting a null reference exception when rendering this razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am following along an mvc tutorial on udemy and I am getting an null reference error. 
when I try to get Model.Name

I am not sure what Im doing wrong here.. I have the code exactly the same was as explained in the tutorial.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vidly.Models;

namespace Vidly.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Movies/Random
        public ActionResult Random()
        {
            var movie = new Movie() { Name="Shrek" };

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

My view has :

```
@model Vidly.Models.Movie

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Random";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model.Id</h2>
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass your model back to the view:

```
return View(movie);
```

Comment: Oh gosh! I see it now. Thanks! I was going crazy not knowing what was going on!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries! If you could accept the answer, that'll help others if they run into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't passed your model to the View.

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    // GET: Movies/Random
    public ActionResult Random()
    {
        var movie = new Movie() { Name="Shrek" };

        //important line
        return View(movie);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass your model to the view.

```
return View(movie);
```